# Why won't my for loop pick up the correct error?

Tags: c++, arrays, 2d

I have a grid and have a member function named Move(int s) that is supposed to move the mover icon in whatever direction it is currently facing, 's' amount of spaces. If there is a block character ('#') anywhere in front of the mover where it wants to move to, the function is supposed to fail and leave the cursor in the correct spot. It seems that the bool statement is always equating to true but I can't seem to find where in my code.

In my sample output the move function never fails, the mover always seems to get through walls or replace walls.

I won't post all 4 direction but I will post North and West:

```
bool Grid::Move(int s) {
bool canMove = true;  //initialize the bool variable
if (direction == NORTH) {
    if ((mRow - s) >= 0) {
        for (int i = mRow; i >= (mRow - s); i--) {
            if (matrix[i][mCol] == '#') {
                canMove = false;
            } else if (matrix[i][mCol] != '#') {
                canMove = true;
            }
        }
        if (canMove == true) {
            matrix[mRow][mCol] = '.';
            mRow = (mRow - s);
            matrix[mRow][mCol] = '^';
            return true;
        }else{
            matrix[mRow][mCol] = '^';
        }
    } else
        return false;
} else if (direction == WEST) {
    if ((mCol - s) >= 0) {
        for (int i = mCol; i >= (mCol - s); i--){
            if (matrix[mRow][i] == '#'){
                canMove = false;
            } else if (matrix[mRow][i] != '#')
                canMove = true;
        }
        if (canMove == true) {
            matrix[mRow][mCol] = '.';
            mCol = (mCol - s);
            matrix[mRow][mCol] = '<';
            return true;
        }else
            matrix[mRow][mCol] = '<';
    }else
        return false;
}
```

Comment: 1. I don't think you have enough code here. 2. You really need to use a debugger to single step through this code looking at the flow and your variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting `canMove` on every iteration of your loop.  Whatever value it gets on the last time thru is the value it will have.

Since the objective there is to see if the move is valid for the entire duration, you don't need to set `canMove` to `true` because once it becomes false it should stay that way.  (And you can `break` out of your loop when that happens.)